# Is there a better way of finding emeralds?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

You see, now emeralds have been added to Minecraft Xbox 360, so I started my search for them in the mines. So far I've found **NOTHING!**

I tried doing branch mining, caving, and I couldn't find a single ore piece. I could only find diamonds, redstone, and gold. I found out they were the rarest ore of all. Is there a way I can get emeralds? I've been mining hours with no success!

Answer (score 2):

This is from the [Wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Emerald_Ore) about Emerald ore:

> Emerald ore is only generated in extreme hills biomes (which actually contain more emerald ore chunks than diamond ore chunks). Due to the nature of the generation algorithm, it may be found a short distance into adjacent biomes, but always within the same chunk as an extreme hills biome.[1] It attempts to generate 3-8 times per each chunk, generating anywhere between layers 4 and 32, meaning it can occur as high up as gold can.
>
> In a world there are about 0.2 emerald ores per chunk. It will only generate in locations which would have otherwise been stone - it is thus possible for as few as 0 to 2 emeralds to generate in a chunk. Found as individual blocks, rather than veins, it can be encountered more commonly than gold, which has a similar range.

Additionally, like the Wiki says emerald ore does not spawn in vines which makes it quite hard to find because it will only be a single block in a large 3d area. Because of this and the fact emerald ore only spawns in a single biome I find it much more difficult to get than gold or diamond.

Also do note that you will not find it in chunks that have been generated before emerald ore got added. You are going to have to travel very far or make a new map.